# Update statement descriptor

Tags: stripe-payments

I have to stripe with two products and cards and bank payments allowed. Whenever a customer subscribe to the product I have to charge them and I have to dynamically set the `statement descriptor`. Is it fine if I listen to `payment_intent_created` webhook and add the `statement_descriptor` there?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, you listen to the webhook event which is triggered when a PaymentIntent is created, and then.. create a new PaymentIntent ? Doesn't really make sense. I'd suggest adding a lot more detail and some code or links to the question.

Comment: @karllekko I have updated the question. I have to set statement_descriptor dynamically whenever new subscription created and charged.

Comment: Then you have to use different Products basically. The statement descriptor comes from the Product used when creating a Subscription. It's too late to set it after the PaymentIntent is already created.